# How does cat know the baud rate of the serial port?

Tags: linux, devices, serial-port

I regularly use `cat` to view debugging information in the console from my FPGA development board over the serial connection, but I never have had to tell linux what the baud rate is. How does cat know what the baud rate of the serial connection is?

Comment: You did not set up the port e.g. with `minicom` before? It doesn't work here. Only after I set up the serial port parameters  I can use `cat`.

Comment: It doesn't set or knows the baudrate, it just reads from the device.

Comment: @Marco, I don't know if Debian has some default baud rate setting, but I haven't set it anywhere.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The [`stty`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/stty.1.html) utility sets or reports on terminal I/O characteristics for the device that is its standard input. These characteristics are used when establishing a connection over that particular medium. `cat` doesn't know the baud rate as such, it rather prints on the screen information received from the particular connection.

As an example `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0` gives the current baud rate for the ttyACM0 device.

Comment: but how did stty know about the baud rate then? This answer only defers somehow the question, if the baud rate can be autodetected or was set at some point (i.e. via `stty`)

Comment: @humanityANDpeace I assume the default baud rate was the one I happened to be using. I later on did need to change it via stty when I changed the baud rate on the device.

Answer (score 9):

`cat` just uses whatever settings the port is already configured for. With this little C snippet you can see the baud rate currently set for a particular serial port:

*get-baud-rate.c*

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  struct termios tios;
  tcgetattr(0, &tios);
  speed_t ispeed = cfgetispeed(&tios);
  speed_t ospeed = cfgetospeed(&tios);
  printf("baud rate in: 0%o\n", ispeed);
  printf("baud rate out: 0%o\n", ospeed);
  return 0;
}
```

Run it:

```
./get-baud-rate < /dev/ttyS0 # or whatever your serial port is
```

The numbers you get can be looked up in `/usr/include/asm-generic/termios.h`, where there are `#define`s such as `B9600` etc. Note that the numbers in the header file and in the `get-baud-rate` output are in octal.

Maybe you can experiment and see what these numbers are like on a fresh boot and whether they change later.

Comment: I just found the `stty` command which does just this. For example, `stty -F /dev/ttyACM0` gives me the current baud rate, which is correct for my device.

Comment: Of course that's a much better idea.

Comment: Is there a way to query the uart clock value as well as the divisor value? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The serial port will `cat` at the previously used baud rate, or the default baud rate.  If you need to change the baud rate you can use `stty` like so:

```bash
stty -F /dev/ttyS1 115200
cat /dev/ttyS1
```

The above commands sets the baud rate of `/dev/ttyS1` to 115200.  Then when you use cat it will work at 115200 baud.